# Quantum theory of a single worldline

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory

In introductions to string theory it is common to start with the quantum theory of a single worldline by quantization of the Polyakov action for some $0$-brane.

What does this theory correspond to, exactly? I know it's not the theory of a single point particle, since those are not well defined for a variety of reasons, and from some arguments of ACuriousMind$^{[1]}$ it may not have a position operator defined. I also know that the full theory of worldlines can be considered as equivalent to QFT, with every worldline diagram corresponding to a Feynman diagram.

Would the theory of a single worldline correspond to the theory of a single QFT particle state because of this?

$  [1]$ private correspondance

Comment: I would help if you could shed some lite on that private correspondence of yours. I see no reason why you shouldn't identify 1-dimensional Polyakov action theory with the relativistic particle. Take a look at my path integral derivation of the Klein-Gordon propagator from the 1-dimensional Polyakov action: http://solenodonus.com/file/path-integral-for-point-particle.html

Comment: @SolenodonParadoxus I guess the issue is what one means by "quantum theory of the relativistic particle". I agree it has the KG propagator, but I believe Slereah's notion of a "particle theory" includes some way to *localize* said particle, i.e. some sort of position operator. I.e. the question here is more whether the quantum theory of the 1d Polyakov action corresponds to the delocalized QFT notion of a particle state or to something closer to a localizable particle state.

Comment: @ACuriousMind please elaborate. What does it mean to have a position operator? Doesn't passing to the Gelfand triple given by the Schwartz space on $R^4$ (together with its algebraic dual and $L_2[R^4]$) make the position operator well-defined? I can also promote the constraint to an operator acting on this algebraic dual space to give the reparametrization invariant dynamics. Or are we talking about something completely different?